# Codeigniter - Call to a member function on a non-object

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have been pulling my hair out for too long looking at this error.  I am using Codeigniter 2 and have created MY_Controller class to load a few settings into my session data.

Which you can see below:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {  
    protected $ajax = 0;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();            
        $this->load->model('settings_model');

        //is the session user agent set
        if ($this->session->userdata('browser') == false)
        {
            $this->load->library('user_agent');
            $this->session->set_userdata(array(
                'browser' => $this->agent->browser(),
                'browser_version' => $this->agent->version(),
                'is_mobile' => $this->agent->is_mobile() ? 1 : 0
            ));                                                          
        }

        //is the settings loaded
        if ($this->session->userdata('league_name') == false)
        {                                       
            $this->Settings_model->get_general_settings();
        }

        //get the menu if we need to
        //if ($this->session->userdata('menu') == false)
            //$this->Settings_model->get_menu_items();  

        //set the main part of the title
        $this->set_title($this->session->userdata('league_name'));

        //get that referring url
        $this->session->set_userdata('refered_from', isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : base_url()); 

        //ajax request
        $this->ajax = isset($_GET['ajax']) ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
```

Where I am running into the problem is I keep getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function get_general_settings() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\osmdev\application\controllers\welcome.php on line 12
```

Here is the Settings_model.php file that I am loading, yes it is in my application/models folder:

```
class Settings_model extends CI_Model 
{                        
    // Call the Model constructor
    function __construct() {         
        parent::__construct();
    }

    //get the general settings
    function get_general_settings() {
        $query = "SELECT setting_id, variable, value FROM settings WHERE non_session = 0";
        $result = $this->db->query($query);

        foreach ($result->result_array() as $row)
            $this->session->set_userdata($row['variable'], stripslashes($row['value']));    
    }

    //get all the settings we have
    function get_all_settings() {        
        $query = "SELECT setting_id, variable, value FROM settings";
        $result = $this->db->query($query);

        foreach ($result->result_array() as $row)
            $this->session->set_userdata($row['variable'], stripslashes($row['value']));
    }

    //get a specfic setting variable
    function get_specific_setting($var) {           
        $query = "SELECT setting_id, variable, value FROM settings WHERE variable = '".$var;
        $result = $this->db->query($query);

        foreach ($result->result_array() as $row)
            $this->session->set_userdata($row['variable'], stripslashes($row['value']));   
    }

    //get a specific type of setting
    function get_type_setting($type) {
        $query = "SELECT setting_id, variable, value FROM settings WHERE action = '".$type;
        $result = $this->db->query($query);

        foreach ($result->result_array() as $row)
            $this->session->set_userdata($row['variable'], stripslashes($row['value']));    
    }

    //get all the menu items
    function get_menu_items($type=0) {
        $query = "SELECT menu_id, title, menu_url, parent_id, level, function_used, perm_id, icon FROM menu WHERE active = 1 AND is_admin_menu = '".$type;
        $result = $this->db->query($query);

        foreach ($result->result_array() as $row)  
            $items[$row['menu_id']] = $row;  

        $this->session->set_userdata('menu', $items);
    }  
}
```

I am trying to call the get_general_settings function.  Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Also forgot to mention if I take that function call out it runs fine with no errors.

Comment: Have you tried $this->settings_model->get_general_settings() vs $this->Settings_model->get_general_settings() (notice the capital was set to lowercase). If that doesnt work then can you post the results of var_dump($this); to this question? Only the portion pertaining to your Settings Model object though.

Comment: So tried the settings_model and got the same error

Comment: var_dump($this->settings_model) gave me this: object(Settings_model)#23 (0) { }

Comment: When I did var_dump($this->Settings_model) I got: NULL

Answer (score 1):

You could try to setup the model to store $row into an array and then return the array.

Your model:

```
function get_general_settings() {
    $rows = array();
    $query = "SELECT setting_id, variable, value FROM settings WHERE non_session = 0";
    $result = $this->db->query($query);

    foreach ($result->result_array() as $row)
        $variable = $row['variable'];
        $value = stripslashes($row['value']);
        $rows[] = $variable[$value];

    return $rows[]
```

Your controller:

```
//is the settings loaded
    if ($this->session->userdata('league_name') == false)
    {                                       
        //set userdata to returned $rows[]
        $this->session->set_userdata($this->Settings_model->get_general_settings());
    }
//echo last_query to test in mysql
$this->db->last_query();
```

See if that will help solve your problem. I would print_r($this->Settings_model->get_general_settings()); just to see if anything was placed in the array.

Then if nothing is there, echo the last_query to see what it's asking MySQL for and then run that returned query in mysql and see if you get at least one row.

Comment: This isn't going to help me because there is nothing in the object $this->Settings_model.  Look at my comment above for what var_dump gives me.

Comment: And you tried echoing your last query? Did the query return rows?

Answer (score 0):

This error can happen when your database user doesn't have select permission for the table you're trying to query. It doesn't make sense, but it happens from time to time.